# Open file in kthread on behalf of a user process

Tags: multithreading, file, kernel

I am writing a linux kernel module which would start a kthread when a user process calls to it (using ioctl).

How can i open a file using this kthread on bahalf of user process, that is, when it returns the user process can access this file itself!?

Answer (score 0):

It's not really sensible to do this.  To open a file that the userspace process can read, you need to return a file descriptor to that process.

Potentially you could return a UNIX-domain socketpair connecting the kernel thread to the userspace thread, and have the kernel thread pass open file descriptors across that socket using a `SCM_RIGHTS` message.

It is likely to be more appropriate, however, to simply open the file in the context of the original process in the `ioctl()` call and return the file descriptor there.